# indexing time(duration) in solr

Tags: solr, facet

I have data about videos that I would like to index in Solr.  One of the fields I want to use for faceting is "runtime".  Is there a specific field type for time durations, as I don't think the Date type would be the correct usage.  Worst case scenario is I translate the runtime into seconds, but I'd love Solr to be able to handle a time duration natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Solr has duration field type, or anything that could mimic that like ie. time field type.

Documentation [Field Types Included with Solr](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr)

Your idea of converting runtime to seconds sounds very reasonable to me.